# Why are variables defined in a case block available in other case blocks?

Tags: java, switch-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are variables not local in case statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104134/why-are-variables-not-local-in-case-statements)

A variable defined in a scope block can't be used outside it. For example, the following code snippet is invalid:

```
{
    int anothervar = 4;
}
{
    System.out.println(anothervar);
}
```

But it looks like a `case` block does not create apart scopes.

```
switch (mode) {
    case ONE:
        dosomething();
        return;
    case TWO:
        int[] someints = new int[] { 2, 3, 5, 7 };
        SomeObject obj = new SomeObject();
        return;
    case THREE:
        someints = new int[] { 1, 4, 6, 8, 9 };
        obj = new SomeObject();
        return;
}
```

Why don't I have to declare `someints` inside the `case THREE` 'block'?
Suppose `mode = THREE`, then the declaration of variable `someints` is never reached, because `case TWO`, where `someints` is declared, is skipped. Or isn't it? **How does it work internally?**

(The chosen answer in [Why are variables not local in case statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104134/why-are-variables-not-local-in-case-statements) states that a switch statement is internally a set of `jump` commands, but still that does not explain where the variable `someints` is declared.)

Comment: @Wooble: As stated in my question, that answer does not explain the initialization of `someints`. In the answer I linked to, `if(a==2) jump ##2;` causes everything below ##1 and above ##2 to be skipped, including possible declarations of variables. How are the variables still be declared?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a local variable's scope is inside a block, as specified in the [Names documentation](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#103228):

> The scope of a local variable declaration in a block (§14.4.2) is the
>   rest of the block in which the declaration appears, starting with its
>   own initializer (§14.4) and including any further declarators to the
>   right in the local variable declaration statement.

A block is defined to have enclosing braces, as written as well in the [Blocks and Statements documentation](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/statements.doc.html#246838):

> A block is a sequence of statements, local class declarations and
>   local variable declaration statements within braces.

Answer (score 0):

Everything inside the `{ }` is in the same scope. If you take out the `return;` in case TWO for example, you can use the variable in case THREE, provided it's initialised.

Answer (score 0):

This is why you sometimes see code with :

```
case 0: {
   // Stuff
}
```

Only the { } delimitates blocks.

Answer (score 0):

A scope of a declaration is marked by `{ ... }` and you may fall from one case in a second. I admit it is a hole though. I believe in an older version of Java one was not allowed to declare on the `case` level and had to add extra braces:

```
case 1: { int x; ... }
```

Comment: You've been able to declare variables in a case (without any extra braces) since Java 1.0.  See http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/first_edition/html/index.html - specifically see sections 14.9 and 14.2

Comment: @Stephen Then it must have been C++. I am getting senile.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answerers (as they noticed, the scope between {} is only one here) I would like to notice, that such practice: declaring of a variable in one case and using it in the other, is **dirty**. Later you can wish to remove or change some case. And if it will be the one with the declaration, you'll have to change another case. This could cause errors.

Think thoroughly - why your variable someints should be in both cases? Is it REALLY the same thing or two different?

If it is the same: 
Better declare the common variables in the default case and put it as the first one.

```
switch (mode) {
    default:
        int[] someints;
        return;
    case ONE:
        dosomething();
        return;
    case TWO:
        someints = new int[] { 2, 3, 5, 7 };
        SomeObject obj = new SomeObject();
        return;
    case THREE:
        someints = new int[] { 1, 4, 6, 8, 9 };
        obj = new SomeObject();
        return;
}
```

Or declare them out of the switch block (it's worse). Or put it somewhere where you define constants.

If they really are different variables (may be only similar in some way):
define in each case a different variable.

BTW: It's a really nice question!