# Java: How to initialize int array in a switch case?

Tags: java, arrays, oop, initialization, int

How can I initialize an integer array in Java like so: `int[] array = {1,2,3};` inside a switch statement?

Currently, I can write:

```
switch(something) {
    case 0: int[] array = {1,2,3}; break;
    default: int[] array = {3,2,1};
}
```

But when I try to access the `array` variable, eclipse will complain that it might not be initialized.

If I try to declare it like `int[] array;` or `int[] array = new int[3];` and then have the switch statement, it would say I am trying to redeclare it.

How can I resolve this issue? Final idea is to be able to initialize an array with 10 values in just one line of code, based on some logic (a switch statement).

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104134/why-are-variables-not-local-in-case-statements

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Put the declaration before the switch statement. You will also need to explicitly instantiate an array of the correct type.

```
int[] array;
switch (something) {
    case 0: array = new int[] {1, 2, 3}; break;
    default: array = new int[] {3, 2, 1};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would tell you to put the array declaration outside the switch block, however, you cannot use `= { 1, 2, 3}` syntax after the declaration. You need to initialize it the regular way, as in `array = new int[] {1, 2, 3};`

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] array;
switch (something) {
    case 0: array = new int[]{1, 2, 3}; break;
    default: array = new int[]{3, 2, 1};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question before. Hope this helps you.

First Mark Byers is absolutely right. Java works with minimal possible scope. so if you try to do

`case 1: int arr = whatever and 
case 2 : int arr = ...` it will give you an error of re-declaration because entire switch is treated as a single scope and there is no case wise / based scope.

Point 2: if you say:

`case 1: int arr = whatever and 
case 2 : arr = ...` assuming that int arr will be compiled and taken from case 1 then you are still wrong and again java will give you the error, based on the principle that `each and every local var has to be declared and initialized before its use.`

so the best way is to declare it outside your switch and define or initialize it in whichever case you prefer.